# How do I change Grails's "daemon port" from 8091 to something else?

Tags: grails

In forked mode (the default) Grails opens a socket on port 8091 for IPC purposes.

If any other non-Grails process was already listeting on that port, you get the following output:

```
|Loading Grails 2.5.0
|Configuring classpath
|Enter a script name to run. Use TAB for completion: 
grails> |Stopping daemon...
grails> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
grails> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
grails> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
grails> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
grails> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
... (forever)
```

If another Grails instance is listening on that port, for example another user's Grails (in a multi-user dev server) then you get a nice stealthy bug: `stop-app` returns with no error, but it stops somebody else's embedded Tomcat, not yours!

This is clearly sub-optimal, so I need a way for each developer to specify his or her "daemon port", alongside their http port (which they are already doing by putting `server.port = N` in `~/.grails/settings.groovy`)

Looking at the source code, I see a `DEFAULT_DAEMON_PORT = 8091` at the top of `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.ForkedGrailsProcess` but I don't see any obvious way to customize it.

Is there a way to change that port, preferably from the user's BulidSettings `~/.grails/settings.groovy`? If there is none, I'll go ahead and submit it as a bug report.

Comment: http://naleid.com/blog/2014/11/10/debugging-grails-forked-mode  Ronny Løvtangen • 6 months ago

After looking at the Grails source code, I found that you can also specify debug opts from the command line:

grails run-app -Dgrails.project.fork.run.debugArgs=-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005

Note that it is not necessary with --debug-fork
 and also http://grails.io/post/43484836985/road-to-grails-2-3-forked-execution.  It would seem you can set it within the JVM config or try it this alternative way as suggested by Ronny

Answer (score 1):

Found it. Thanks to @vahid for the pointers.

You have to copy the entire `grails.project.fork` map from you project's `BuildConfig.groovy` into your `~/.grails/settings.groovy` and add a **different** `daemonPort: N` value at the end of each sub-map (test, run, war…)

Example:

```
grails.project.fork = [
    test:    [..., daemonPort: 8xx1],
    run:     [..., daemonPort: 8xx2],
    war:     [..., daemonPort: 8xx3],
    console: [..., daemonPort: 8xx4],
]
```